# I am using wazuh and get alert SSH Configuration - Empty passwords permitted

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

mail->rootcheck
Rule: 516 (level 3) -> 'System Audit event.'
System Audit: CIS - RHEL7 - 6.2.9 - SSH Configuration - Empty passwords permitted {CIS: 6.2.9 RHEL7} {PCI_DSS:                            4.1}. File: /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Reference: https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/linux/CIS_Red_Hat_Enterpr                           ise_Linux_7_Benchmark_v1.1.0.pdf .
title: CIS - RHEL7 - 6.2.9 - SSH Configuration - Empty passwords permitted
file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config

What does it mean with SSH Configuration - Empty passwords permitted?

I found this on redhat archive :

On a standard installation of FC1 and FC2 (and FC3?) is permit to login
with a user with a empty password ... is this correct?

How to disable this "feature"?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change PermitEmptyPasswords yes (to no) and restart sshd. Then check how this was allowed in the first place and ensure whatever caused it does not happen again.

Comment: [root igloo root]# man sshd_config
PermitEmptyPasswords
When password authentication is allowed, it specifies whether the
server allows login to accounts with empty password strings.  The
default is ânoâ.
[root igloo root]# grep PermitEmptyPasswords /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
[root igloo root]# useradd nopasswd
[root igloo root]# passwd -d nopasswd
Removing password for user nopasswd.
passwd: Success

Comment: [root igloo root]# ssh nopasswd localhost
nopasswd localhost's password: <type ENTER>
Permission denied, please try again.
nopasswd localhost's password: <type "x" then ENTER>
[nopasswd igloo nopasswd]$ id
uid=505(nopasswd) gid=507(nopasswd) gruppi=507(nopasswd)
[nopasswd igloo nopasswd]$

Could you explain it?

Comment: Why is the PermitEmptyPasswords line commented out? Remove the # at the start of the line.